# could I use something like a magic amulet while it's not on my neck?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, equipment

What is defined as 'worn'? Does an amulet or ring have to be on my neck or finger specifically or do I just have to be carrying it somewhere on my body or even in my backpack?
For instance, if I had a Clockwork Amulet on my belt, does that constitute as me 'wearing' it so I could use it?

Comment: Hi Anon, I've marked your question as a duplicate because I believe it has been asked an answered before. This is not intended as a punishment of any kind; it's just to redirect users to the "main" question, I guess you could call it. If the 2 linked questions in the banner *don't* answer your question sufficiently please [edit] your question with further detail about what's confusing you and how those other questions don't provide a sufficient answer.